# My javascript code crashes after about 5 cycles. I'm new to js. Probably not garbage collecting

Tags: javascript, browser

Hopefully one of you guys can solve this. I'm writing a game which works with a deck of playing cards. I have all 52 cards scanned into image files and also the back of the card (so 53 cards all up)
The cards change regularly (after every round which only takes about 5 - 8 seconds tops.

As you tell there are clickable image cards (shown in the below 2 lines - There are 5 usually but shortened for the example) Clicking on a card lets you discard it which of course flips the card to show it will be discarded or if clicked again loads the card again. (card flipping routine not shown and is not the problem directly)

When you click a card certain calculations are done according to the game rules (NOT SHOWN)
This changes the card values by changing the image of the card (changing the URL originally displayed) which works fine for about 5 changes. After that the browser freezes.
I'm assuming that the script is using too much memory or something but I'm not sure. My machine has 64 gigs so its not system memory failing.

I've tried hiding the card first then reloading . I've tried setting the attribute to none.. ie `document.getElementbyId("card01").none`

As you can guess I'm still new and learning javascript. Everything else works in the game however.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<input type = "image"
     onclick ="somethingclicked('card1')"
 id = "card01"
 
     < img src="cards/playingcardback.PNG" width = 200 > 
</button>

    <input type = "image"
     onclick ="somethingclicked('card2')"
 id = "card02"
 
     < img src="cards/playingcardback.PNG" width = 200 > 
</button>

<script>
```

// I've also got a function which grabs new cards after checking if the card is already used (this works but I've trimmed it down for the example here

```
randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 52) + 1);
if (usedcards[randomnumber] ==0)
{
usedcards[randomnumber] = 1; // add it to the list of used numbers
computercards[counter] = cards[randomnumber]; // Find the card name from cards[] and give it to the computer
counter++; // Increase the number of cards the computer has to eventually jump out of the while loop
}
```

// Once out of the choosing cards loop it posts the new cards (showing only 2 here in this example)

```
document.getElementById("card01").src = "cards/"+playercards[0]+".PNG";
document.getElementById("card02").src = "cards/"+playercards[1]+".PNG";
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementbyId("card01").none` doesn't do anything - also `When you click a card` ... where's the code that handles this? you havne't shown it, yet that's where you say the problem is - you mention some "choosing cards loop" - again, something you haven't shown - you haven't really shown anything that would cause the issue you've described

Comment: Your html snippet is not valid (closing `</button>` without opening one, `<input>` element is missing the ending '>'...).  Moreover, what are you trying to do with this: `document.getElementById("card01").src`? The id "card01" is set on a input element and there's not `src` attribute on that.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't notice the </button> bit but yeah, it still worked. As for the src element on document.getElementbyId("card01").src I am changing the path to the picture file which is the card.

Comment: Jaromanda X , The problem is not in the routine which chooses the new card. The problem is.. The browser freezes after about 5 turns of swapping 5 cards with document.getElementById("card01").src = "cards/newcardname.jpg";   // Well it chooses the new card name but you get the point. It does this by a list of what card is called with 3 variables... ie 3 diamonds. So if the card number is 3 and the suit is diamonds it will make a filename 3diamonds.jpg. So the new src is cards/3diamonds.jpg

Comment: For whoever wanted the processing code for when a card is clicked...function somethingclicked(id)
{
if (id =="card3")
{
document.getElementById("card03").src ="pokercards/playingcards_3h.PNG";
}

Comment: A further note to everyone... playercards[0] contains the cards filename minus the .PNG extension.. ie 3diamonds, 7hearts, etc etc.

Comment: I made this much simpler with the whole script. Here goes.... <input type = "image"
  onclick ="somethingclicked('card1')"
 id = "card01"
 
     < img src="pokercards/playingcardback.PNG" width = 200 > 
</input>

<script>
var playingcards = ["2diamonds","3diamonds","4diamonds","5diamonds","6diamonds","7diamonds"]

function somethingclicked(id)
{
if (id == "card1")
{
randomnumber = randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
document.getElementById("card01").src = "pokercards/"+playingcards[randomnumber]+".PNG";

}
}

</script>

Comment: This one doesn't seem to crash. I'm going to have to go right through my code again. Maybe I'm missing a variable in one of the cards. Thanks to the guys who commented. I'll post a new question with the whole script if I can't fix it.